# sshpass still asking password while trying to login to sftp server in Linux

Tags: linux, login, sftp, sshpass

Im trying to login to one of the server using sftp. The connecting server not allows ssh key based login. So i have used sshpass to login to the server. But the problem is it' still prompting me to enter the password eventhough i have passed the password using -p option in sshpass. Below is the commands i tried using to connect to the server but still prompting the password. Even after entering the password it's not going to the sftp server and it is getting stucked there for life time.

```
SSHPASS='********' sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - sftp- 
user@host
sshpass -p ******* sftp user@host
sshpass -p ****** sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
user@host
```

After entering the above commands below is the response i get. Even if i enter the password it stays there without doing anything.

```
Connecting to host...
Password authentication
```

PS: I should not use ssh based login because the other team owner are not allowing it.

Edit Update:

Adding the output after using the vvv option in the sftp

```
Connecting to host******...
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to Host******** [*******] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/lpadmin/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/lpadmin/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/lpadmin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lpadmin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lpadmin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lpadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/lpadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Cleo 
Harmony/5.6.1.0 SSH FTP server
debug1: no match: Cleo Harmony/5.6.1.0 SSH FTP server
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 864 bytes for a total of 885
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie- 
hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman- 
group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert- 
v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert- 
v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128- 
cbc,3des- 
cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael- 
cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128- 
cbc,3des- 
cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael- 
cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2- 
256,hmac- 
sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2- 
256,hmac- 
sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman- 
group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1- 
sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192- 
cbc,aes192- 
ctr,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,arcfour128,arcfour256,blowfish-cbc,cast128- 
cbc,twofish128-cbc,twofish192-cbc,twofish256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192- 
cbc,aes192- 
ctr,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,arcfour128,arcfour256,blowfish-cbc,cast128- 
cbc,twofish128-cbc,twofish192-cbc,twofish256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac- 
md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac- 
md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 909
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 163/320
debug2: bits set: 4124/8192
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: Wrote 1040 bytes for a total of 1949
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host host********* filename 
/home/lpadmin/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host host****** filename 
/home/lpadmin/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 11
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host IP****** filename 
/home/lpadmin/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host IP****** filename 
/home/lpadmin/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 11
debug1: Host 'Host******' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/lpadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug2: bits set: 4116/8192
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1965
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 52 bytes for a total of 2017
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/lpadmin/.ssh/id_rsa (0x560cc4a8ec70)
debug2: key: /home/lpadmin/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/lpadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug3: Wrote 84 bytes for a total of 2101
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list password,keyboard- 
interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard- 
interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 100 bytes for a total of 2201
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
Password authentication
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`sshpass` isn't recognizing the password prompt, so it's not sending the password. Sshpass version 1.06 and later has a command-line option "-P" to specify the password prompt that it should look for. Try running sshpass like this:

```
SSHPASS='********' sshpass -e -P 'Password authentication' sftp ...
```

This tells sshpass what password prompt it should respond to.

The remote SSH server is trying to do a type of authentication called "keyboard-interactive". The server sends a prompt message to the client, the client presents the prompt to the user, the user responds, and the client sends the response to the server. This is like password authentication, except that the remote server provides the text of the prompt.

In this case, the prompt is the text "Password authentication". Sshpass doesn't recognize this as a password prompt, so it doesn't send the password. The sshpass "-P" option tells sshpass what prompt to look for, instead of its built-in default.

Running "sshpass -V" will produce the version of the sshpass that you're running. "sshpass -h" will print a short description of its command-line options, including -P if it's a version that includes that feature.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation .The version we are using is 10.5 and i don't find that option. Is there any another way that we can handle this issue?

Comment: The preferred way to do this is to use an ssh key instead of automating a password response, and personally I'd push back on this other team that isn't permitting that. Aside from that, sshpass is [open source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/), so one option might be to build your own copy from source code. Some people will use expect to automate responding to password prompts.